# Angular validation issue AND OR

Tags: html, angularjs, validation

I'm having an issue with my angular validation. I have an input that seems to be acting strangely. This is the snippet of code:

```
<input name="username" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="user.username" ng-minlength="4" ng-maxlength="12" ng-change="checkUsername(user.username);" required/>
        <span ng-show="doesUserExist || submitted && registerForm.username.$error.required || submitted && registerForm.username.$invalid" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>
```

Does userexist is just a call to the service that validates the username availability. Submitted is set to true when the user submits the data via the form. Then the rest of the validation is basic angular validation stuff. For some reason even though all submitted && registerForm.username.$error.required and submitted && registerForm.username.$invalid are equal to true the overall statement equates to false. This only occurs after submit is equal to true when the user first submits the data. This basically means my glyphicon wont reappear when the user makes mistakes. Any suggestions, I'd be extremely grateful. Thanks very much i'm sure i've just missed something silly.

So in summary

```
{{doesUserExist}] - false
{{registerForm.username.$error.required}} - true
{{registerForm.username.$invalid}} - true
{{doesUserExist || submitted && registerForm.username.$error.required || submitted && {{registerForm.username.$invalid}} - false
```

Comment: {{doesUserExist || submitted && registerForm.username.$error.required || submitted && registerForm.username.$invalid}}
in last line there was extra {{

Comment: and please use "( )" to ensure that which operation should fire first..

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the assistance. Turns out the issue was the service was returning a string... So angular was freaking out a bit when I changed it to doesUserExist === 'true' everything seemed to be fine